# What’s the meaning of `Duration: 30.18s, Total samples = 26.26s (87.00%)` in go pprof?

Tags: go

As my understanding, pprof stops and samples go program at every 10ms. So a 30s program should got 3000 samples, but what’s the meaning of the 26.26s? How can the samples count be shown as time duration?

What’s more, I even ever got such output shows that the sample time is bigger than wall time, how could it be such result?

`Duration: 5.13s, Total samples = 5.57s (108.58%)`

Comment: Concurrency. If two CPU cores are busy for one second on the wall clock, they have been used for two seconds. It's the same mechanism that allows YouTube to add several hundred hours of Video every minute.

Comment: @Peter Thanks a lot, while maybe I shouldn't put two questions into one post.  I want to ask what the `26.26s` stands for? since the wall time is `30.18s`, what the program was doing during the other `30.18 - 26.26 = 3.92s`?  Is it not on CPU because of blocking on something.  While I think even no goroutine is on CPU, there should be something running on CPU (like idle thread?)

Comment: regarding the missing seconds particularly, in my experience pprof generally shows you the beginning of the 'long tail' because you are not generally interested in the many many things that take very little time.

Answer (score 0):

That confusing wording was reported in [`google/pprof` issue 128](https://github.com/google/pprof/issues/128)

> The "`Total samples`" part is confusing.
> Milliseconds are continuous, but samples are discrete — they're individual points, so how can you sum them up into a quantity of milliseconds?
>
> The "sum" is the sum of a discrete number (a quantity of samples), not a continuous range (a time interval).
> Reporting the sums makes perfect sense, but reporting discrete numbers using continuous units is just plain confusing.
>
> Please update the formatting of the Duration line to give a clearer indication of what a quantity of samples reported in milliseconds actually means.

Raul Silvera's answer:

> Each callstack in a profile is associated to a set of values. What is reported here is the sum of these values for all the callstacks in the profile, and is useful to understand the weight of individual frames over the full profile.
>
> We're reporting the sum using the unit described in the profile.
> Would you have a concrete suggestion for this example?
> Maybe just a rewording would help, like:
>
> ```
> Duration: 1.60s, Samples account for 14.50ms (0.9%)
> ```

---

There are still pprof improvements discussed for pprof in [`golang/go` issue 36821](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36821)

> `pprof` CPU profiles lack accuracy (closeness to the ground truth) and precision (repeatability across different runs).
>
> The issue is with the use of OS timers used for sampling; OS timers are coarse-grained and have a high skid.
>
> I will propose a design to extend CPU profiling by sampling CPU Performance Monitoring Unit (PMU) aka hardware performance counters

It includes examples where `Total samples` exceeds duration.

> ### Dependence on the number of cores and length of test execution:
>
> The results of `goroutine.go` test depend on the number of CPU cores available.
>
> On a multi-core CPU, if you set `GOMAXPROCS=1`, `goroutine.go` will not show a huge variation, since each goroutine runs for several seconds.
>
> However, if you set `GOMAXPROCS` to a larger value, say 4, you will notice a significant measurement attribution problem.
> One reason for this problem is that the `itimer` samples on Linux are not guaranteed to be delivered to the thread whose timer expired.

---

Since Go 1.17 (and improved in Go 1.18), you can add **[pprof labels](https://github.com/DataDog/go-profiler-notes/blob/main/guide/README.md#cpu-profiler-labels)** to know more:

> A cool feature of Go's CPU profiler is that you can attach arbitrary key value pairs to a goroutine. These labels will be inherited by any goroutine spawned from that goroutine and show up in the resulting profile.

> Let's consider the example below that does some CPU `work()` on behalf of a user.
> By using the `pprof.Labels()` and `pprof.Do()` API, we can associate the user with the goroutine that is executing the `work()` function.
> Additionally the labels are automatically inherited by any goroutine spawned within the same code block, for example the `backgroundWork()` goroutine.
>
> ```golang
> func work(ctx context.Context, user string) {
>   labels := pprof.Labels("user", user)
>   pprof.Do(ctx, labels, func(_ context.Context) {
>       go backgroundWork()
>       directWork()
>   })
> }
> ```
>
> [image: https://github.com/DataDog/go-profiler-notes/raw/main/guide/cpu-profiler-labels.png]
>
> How you use these labels is up to you.
> You might include things such as user ids, request ids, http endpoints, subscription plan or other data that can allow you to get a better understanding of what types of requests are causing high CPU utilization, even when they are being processed by the same code paths.
>
> That being said, using labels will increase the size of your `pprof` files. So you should probably start with low cardinality labels such as endpoints before moving on to high cardinality labels once you feel confident that they don't impact the performance of your application.